# how to pass dynamic value to $in in mongodb aggregation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregate, aggregation

I have two collections 1 is campaigns and other is orders.
I have to filter orders for each campaign. So what I am doing is that I'm fetching all the campaigns and after that I'm looking up for the orders that matches some specific criteria.

```
[
     { 
       $match: { type: 'FOLLOWUP' } 
     },
     {
       $lookup: {
         from: 'orders',
         as: 'orders',
         pipeline: [
           {
              $match: {
                 'status': { $in: '$activeFilter' }
              }
           }
         ]
       }
     }
]
```

In above example `status` contain some specific string and the `activeFilter` has array of string containing active status for that campaign. `activeFilter` is an array but I'm getting error that `$in` needs an array.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where does activeFilter come from? Do you mean to put `$in: activeFilter`?

Comment: activeFilter is an array saved in campaign, its different for each campaign and it's coming from campaign document thats why I have written '$activeFilter' its not a variable in my code.

Comment: Ok. If the first step of your pipeline returns many campaigns, each with a different  list of many elements in activeFilter, how exactly do you expect it to work in the oders match step? Is it supposed to be a concat of all the different activeFilters? Is is supposed to be a specific activeFilter? You might want to start here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#std-label-lookup-join-pipeline

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using Aggregation pipeline, and `$in` operator does not work the same in `find()` query and in Aggregation pipeline. In Aggregation pipeline, syntax is as follow:

```
{ $in: [ <expression>, <array expression> ] }
```

So, `$in` should have 2 parameters where `value` is the first one, and `array` is the second one. You should change your code like this:

```
"$match": {
  "$expr": {
    "$in": ["$status", "$activeFilter"]
  }
}
```

[Working example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/jhR1yVR8X1X)